# cannot read property of map undefined using React redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, undefined, react-props

I'm trying to add information to a component but as soon as I click on the form button I get cannot read property map of undefined. Please help. 
I've checked all the Db and routes, reducers etc. and they're all fine.

Here is component containing the form (The console.log returns "undefined")

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addExercise } from "../actions/exercises";

class CreateExercise extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newExercise: {},
    };
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.reset();
    this.props.dispatch(addExercise(this.state.newExercise));
  }

  updateDetails(e) {
    let newExercise = this.state.newExercise;
    newExercise[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ newExercise });
  }
  render() {
    console.log("anything", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <h2>Exercise Form</h2>
          <div className="form">
            <div>
              <label>Name of Exercise:</label>
              <input
                name="exe_name"
                type="text"
                onChange={this.updateDetails.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Exercise Info:</label>
              <input
                name="exe_info"
                type="text"
                onChange={this.updateDetails.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Exercise Url:</label>
              <input
                name="exe_url"
                type="text"
                onChange={this.updateDetails.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Exercise Url2:</label>
              <input
                name="exe_url2"
                type="text"
                onChange={this.updateDetails.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Comment:</label>
              <input
                name="comment"
                type="text"
                onChange={this.updateDetails.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <select name="plan_id" onChange={this.updateDetails.bind(this)}>
            <option>Enter plan details</option>
            {this.props.plans.map((plan, i) => {
              return <option value={plan.plan_id}>{plan.sets}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
          <input className="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>;
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ plans }) => {
  return { plans };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CreateExercise);
```

And here is the App component where it's being called.

```
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getExercises } from "../actions/exercises";
import { getPlansRequest } from "../actions/plansActions";
import ExerciseList from "./ExerciseList";
import Header from "./Header";
import CreateExercise from "./CreateExercise";
import Single from "./Single";
import About from "./About";
import Home from "./Home";
import CreatePlan from "./CreatePlan";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showExerciseForm: false,
      showPlanForm: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getPlansRequest());
    this.props.dispatch(getExercises());
  }

  toggleForm(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: !this.state[e.target.name] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="app-container">
          <div className="sidebar pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4">
            <Header />
          </div>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() => (
              <button
                name="showExerciseForm"
                onClick={this.toggleForm.bind(this)}
              >
                {this.state.showExerciseForm ? "Cancel" : "Create Exercise"}
              </button>
            )}
          />

          {this.state.showExerciseForm && (
            <Route exact path="/" component={CreateExercise} />
          )}

          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() => (
              <button name="showPlanForm" onClick={this.toggleForm.bind(this)}>
                {this.state.showPlanForm ? "Cancel" : "Create Plan"}
              </button>
            )}
          />
          {this.state.showPlanForm && (
            <Route exact path="/" component={CreatePlan} />
          )}

          <Route exact path="/exercises" component={ExerciseList} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/exercises/:id"
            component={props => <Single {...props} />}
          />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(App);
```

Comment: Please indent your code and provide a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You must send some props in the route to fetch them in component

In App component

```
{this.state.showExerciseForm && (<Route exact path="/" foobar="Something" component={CreateExercise} />)}
```

In CreateExercise fetch props by

```
this.props.foobar
```

Comment: Hi, sorry can you be a bit more precise? Not sure how exactly this is going to help.

Comment: You need to send parameter in the route tag similar to foobar with some value, I have added inside route tag to send.